# R data frame: Transposing rows into a column in a cycle

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, reshape, transpose

I am in a bit of a program block with the restructuring of my data frame.

I have a following data frame structure:

```
> nrow(data)
[1] 731
> ncol(data)
[1] 25

HE01 HE02 HE03 ... HE24 HE25
1)value1 value 2 value 3 ... value 24 value 25
...
731) value 1 value 2 value 3 ... value 24 value 25
```

My purpose is to restructure the data in the following way:
1) putting the column names in a specific column in the front
2) inserting the values from every row in a column next to each of the corresponding column names and this in a cycle from 1 to 25 and then again.

Somehow like this:

```
HE01 value 1
HE02 value 2
...
HE25 value 25
and again for row number two
HE01 value 1
...
HE25 value 25
and again in this pattern till row number 731
```

I assume this could be done with some sort of a loop but can't figure out exactly how.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: `melt` from reshape2 perhaps? Or `stack`?

Comment: relevant search terms are "wide format" and "long format".

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't like answering in comments....

Imagine you're starting with this:

```
set.seed(1)
M <- data.frame(
  matrix(rnorm(25), ncol = 5,
         dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("HE", 1:5))))
M
#          HE1        HE2        HE3         HE4         HE5
# 1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 -0.04493361  0.91897737
# 2  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432 -0.01619026  0.78213630
# 3 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406  0.94383621  0.07456498
# 4  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999  0.82122120 -1.98935170
# 5  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309  0.59390132  0.61982575
```

Try:

```
stack(M)
```

or

```
reshape(M, direction = "long", varying = 1:5, sep = "")
```

or

```
data.frame(ind = rep(names(M), each = ncol(M)), 
           val = unlist(M))
```

or

```
library(reshape2)
melt(M)
```

---

Given your described problem, the first option makes the most sense to me.